# Print from first instance text A to first instance of text B

Tags: awk

I have the following array inside a program:

```
  ... #code
  $packages = [ 
    'git',        # version control
     ...
    'iftop',      # monitor network usage by ip
    'iotop',      # monitor io usage
  ]
  ... #more code
```

I want to use `awk` to print lines from the first occurrence of $packages to the first ending `]`, after the occurrence of `$packages`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the records, keep an identifier for `$packages`, print lines when the identifier is set, and exit after printing when you find next `]`:

```
awk '/\$packages/ {c=1; print; next} /\]/ {print; exit}; c{print}'
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt 
  ... #code
  $packages = [ 
    'git',        # version control
     ...
    'iftop',      # monitor network usage by ip
    'iotop',      # monitor io usage
  ]
  ... #more code

  ... #code
  $packages = [ 
    'git',        # version control
     ...
    'iftop',      # monitor network usage by ip
    'iotop',      # monitor io usage
  ]
  ... #more code

% awk '/\$packages/ {c=1; print; next} /\]/ {print; exit}; c{print}' file.txt   
  $packages = [ 
    'git',        # version control
     ...
    'iftop',      # monitor network usage by ip
    'iotop',      # monitor io usage
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

We use the `range` operator `,` of `sed` to select the range of lines we are interested in. For this scenario, the range begins with the string `$package` and ends with `]` (on different lines).

First we reject any lines outside of the range, `/\$package/,/]/!d` and then from the range we print them all (due to the implicit printing of the pattern space property of `sed`) BUT `quit` as soon as the line with the string `]` is met. it implies, we have printed to stdout the first of the ranges `/\$package/,/]/`

```
sed -e '/\$packages/,/]/!d; /]/q' yourfile
sed -n '/\$packages/,/]/p; /]/q' yourfile
```